# Speed differences between Table, Replace, Array, Map, and AssociationMap

Tags: performance-tuning, replacement, parallelization, list-manipulation

EDIT: Actually, it looks like part of this is bogus—`Array` doesn't actually work on this input (I'm often a little shaky on what kind of input, exactly, works for interpolated functions...) which I should have realized from the flat timing curve. `Array` is now in line with the non-`Table` cluster, making `Table` the fastest (but still slower than I'd like). The image has been updated. I also think that I should maybe rerun these with `AbsoluteTiming`; I'm seeing some disparity here and there.

I have a function `f` which is an `Interpolation` of two variables, say `x` and `y`. In my full use case, I have 200 different such `f`s, and each one should act on a simple 674x674 array which is just an array of coordinates (i.e. just `{{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{2, 1},...` if the arrays in question were only 3x3).

There seem to be a *lot* of ways to do this, and I don't know how to pick the best one, why the best one *is* the best one, or even whether the best one that I've found is indeed the best! `Array` seems to be tailor-made for this use-case, but I don't understand why everything else is so much worse (also, I could swear I had clocked `AssociationMap` as faster last night, but it looks like I must not have—I think that the `Table` vs. `ParallelTable` issue mentioned below must account for that).

Here are the ways I've tried, as well as the `Timing` results for running them for arrays of size up to 100x100.

```
TableTiming = Table[First@Timing@Table[f, {x, i}, {y, i}], {i, 100}];

ReplaceTiming = Table[With[{z = Table[{x -> a, y -> b}, {a, i}, {b,i}]}, First@Timing[f /. z]], {i, 100}];

g2[i_, j_] := f /. {x -> i, y -> j}

ArrayTiming = Table[First@Timing[g2~Array~{i, i}], {i, 100}];

g[{i_, j_}] := f /. {x -> i, y -> j}

MapTiming = Table[With[{z = Flatten[Table[{a, b}, {a, i}, {b, i}], 1]}, First@Timing[g /@ z]], {i, 100}];

AssociationMapTiming = Table[With[{z = Flatten[Table[{a, b}, {a, i},{b, i}], 1]}, First@Timing[Values@AssociationMap[g, z]]], {i, 100}];
```

The results:

[image]

Results using `AbsoluteTiming`:

[image]

<del>`Array` works basically like I'd expect—after all, even though `f` is not a beautiful function given that it's a `ListInterpolation` over a surface, finding these values amounts to plugging two integers into a polynomial—it doesn't seem like it should take very long.</del> My curiosity is regarding why `Replace`, `Map`, and `AssociationMap` all seem to come out the same, `Table` seems to be middling<del>, and `Array` destroys them all.</del> I don't understand the underlying mechanisms that should determine these trends.

I also stumbled upon a weird (to me) issue where using `ParallelTable` to calculate these `Timing`s resulted in **huge** disparities, as shown below.

[image: Table vs. ParallelTable]

I don't understand why this is happening, either, and it has me wondering whether I have code hanging around that would run much more quickly with `Table` vs. `ParallelTable` :/. This turned out not to be unique to `AssociationMap`, either—why does this happen, and how can I avoid falling prey to it in the future?

I have two followup questions, as well:

1. Is <del>`Array`</del> `Table` the best way to implement this, or is there another way to go about this?
2. If I don't care about the individual values, but only care about applying `Mean@Abs@Flatten@#&` to the final arrays, is there trick I could use to speed this up further? (UPDATE: `Sum[Abs@f,{x,674},{y,674}]/674^2` is the fastest yet, actually—very reasonably so.)

Comment: Just a few remarks... Since your operations all run quite fast, you might want to use `RepeatedTiming` to benchmark the speed. This averages over multiple runs and is "better" I believe if your operations just take a few seconds at most. W.r.t. `(Parallel)Table` timings: your calculations are pretty fast, so `ParallelTable` will not help because there's a huge overhead due to data exchange between local and master kernel. `ParallelTable` is useful when each evaluation takes quite a long time, if you search SE here you will find many questions on that

Comment: @Lukas good call on `ParallelTable`; I knew about that but never considered that the overhead would be that massive. At least the other operations that I use that and `ParallelMap` for are much more complicated, so that jives with what you've said as well. I could use `RepeatedTiming`, but the given results for CPU timing are pretty replicable and I'm not too worried about them.

Comment: Try setting your function Listable, that can, in most cases, surpass all these solutions in speed. :)

Comment: @Wjx that's a great idea! I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this with the results of an `InterpolatingFunction`, though. I start out with such a function, but the `f` in my above post is in terms of derivatives of that interpolating function. I just slightly rewrote it so that I keep `f` a pure function instead of plugging in `x` and `y` to take explicit derivatives—but now I can't even feed it arguments, it seems.

Regardless of that: Setting, say, `g` to `Listable` causes it to act come out like `{{g[1], g[1]}, {g[1], g[2]},...` instead of making it take the {i,j} input.